# What spell did Gandalf cast when he revived Pippin?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, gandalf

In the movies, Pippin takes the Palantir and 'talks' to Sauron. Afterwards, he seems to have died, or at least gone unconscious. Gandalf then said some words, probably casting a spell. Was it some sort of a resurrection spell?

Comment: What do you mean? He obviously cast "[Rennervate!](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Reviving_Spell)" --- sorry, wrong Gandalf.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the books, Gandalf doesn't say anything to revive Pippin; if he does perform magic, it's of a silent, non-verbal variety. To bring Pippin back to full awareness after he hypnotically delivers the message from Sauron, all he says is "Come back!" I interpreted this as just a natural thing for anyone to say to a person in a trance, but it's possible it was some kind of spell. Here's the relevant passage (emphasis mine):

> He knelt by Pippin's body: the hobbit was lying on his back, rigid, with unseeing eyes staring up at the sky. "The devilry! What mischief has he done - to himself, and to all of us?" The wizard's face was drawn and haggard.
>
> **He took Pippin's hand and bent over his face, listening for his breath; then he laid his hands on his brow.** The hobbit shuddered. His eyes closed. He cried out; and sat up, staring in bewilderment at all the faces round him, pale in the moonlight.
>
> "It is not for you, Saruman!" he cried in a shrill and toneless voice, shrinking away from Gandalf. "I will send for it at once. Do you understand? Say just that!" Then he struggled to get up and escape, but Gandalf held him gently and firmly.
>
> **"Peregrin Took!" he said. "Come back!"**
>
> The hobbit relaxed and fell back, clinging to the wizard's hand. "Gandalf!" he cried. "Gandalf! Forgive me!"
>
> <sup>-- *The Two Towers*, chapter 11: *The Palantir*</sup>

Comment: `He dried out;` Hobbit jerky?

Comment: @Xantec Rofl :-D Typo, fixed now. (I transcribed this passage by hand from the book.)

Comment: There is another reference to spoken magic in the Fellowship of the Ring. When making their escape from the Chamber of Mazarbul, Gandalf turned back to face whatever was pursuing them (unbeknowst to them, the Balrog). After a while, he returns, exhausted, and mentions having to speak a "Word of Command" (both words capitalised) to stop the whatever-it-was from opening the door and following them down the stairs. It could be that a similar kind of magic was used to summon Pippin and wake him from his stupor.

Comment: @randal'thor Pressed enter by mistake, then couldn't edit the comment in time, so I deleted it and wrote it out again.

Comment: This answers with respect to the book, but the question is about the movie?

Comment: @MattGutting The films are based on the books, which are the more canonical source. But if you have a good film-based answer which contradicts this, go ahead and post it - I'll upvote.

Comment: It's been 15 years since I saw the films. I just thought the wording of the question seemed to be asking whether *in the films* Gandalf was speaking any particular spell.

Answer (score 3):

This fits with the form of the majority of Gandalf's magic. His will, expressed in ordinary words, is magic more powerful than that of Saruman or the Enemy. He puts forth all his strength to help Bilbo leave the ring behind, and uses similar methods to heal Theoden and Pippin.

Gandalf's other main expression of magic is simply his presence, as when he uncloaks himself in wrath at the Battle of Helm's Deep.

Gandalf's power is much more in who he is than in any magical spell.